# Laravel Cancel Job Batch Speed Issue

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs, laravel-horizon

Laravel 8 is introduce the Job Batching for the queue management. Where all the jobs is within one batch and we will play with batch if we want to. I have a issue with cancelling the batch. When we are cancelling the batch at that time it will auto delete the jobs which are pending to execute within that batch. Do anyone knows how to speed up that deleting speed while cancelling the batch? Any different redis connection we can provide while deleting those jobs?

I tried to check the BatchRepository and its related classes. But I could not found anything. When I start the job I use the `RateLimited` middleware. Is there any class, while at the time of cancelling the batch we can also increase the rate to delete the jobs.